# Are eslint warnings for missing dependencies in React hooks always correct?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm wondering if eslint rule for mising dependencies in React hooks is always correct. In my example I have `calendarIds` object in the state. 
When the query is `current-day` I initialize the `calendarIds` object to some data.
If the page query params change from `curent-day` to something else I want to reset the `calendarIds` object:

```
const {calendarData, query} = props
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useeffect2');
    if (query['date-range'] === 'current-day') {
      const [currentDay = { events: [] }] = calendarData;
      const events = currentDay.events.reduce((acc, { calendarId, actual, trend }) => {
          acc[calendarId] = { actual: actual || Math.round(Math.random() * 1000),
            trend };
          return acc;
      }, {});

      console.log(CALENDAR_IDS, 'events', events);
      setState({
        type: CALENDAR_IDS,
        payload: events
      });
    } else if (state.realTimeData.calendarIds) {
      setState({
        type: CALENDAR_IDS,
        payload: {}
      });
    }
  }, [calendarData, query]);
```

The dependencies array includes `calendarData` and `query` which trigger the function. In the `else if` I check if I have the `calendarIds` in the state already, if yes I reset it.

As a result I get a missing dependency for `state.realTimeData.calendarIds`. However I don't see why this would be a problem to not include it in the dependencies array. On the contrary, it may even trigger an infinite loop of state updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useEffect is depending on `state.realTimeData.calendarIds` being defined which is why you're getting that warning. You're using value outside of the useEffect context. You're also overriding your `state.realTimeData.calendarIds` data with your `setState`; not sure if that's intentional. An easy fix is to use a ref for the conditional, so you can rely on not causing an infinite loop.